# The determinant of the jacobi matrix of $x\mapsto \frac{x}{|x|^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, derivatives, determinant

I want to calculate the determinant of the jacobian of the map

$\phi$: $\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$, $x\mapsto \frac{x}{|x|^2}$

Since this maps doesnt seems to be linear I dont know how to do it :/

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What is the $(i, j)$ entry of a Jacobian matrix of a given map $\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$?

Comment: It is the entry $\partial_jf_i$, right?

Comment: Yes. So, for your $\phi$, what is $\phi_i$? What is $\partial_j \phi_i$?

Comment: We have $\phi_i(x)=\frac{x_i}{|x|^2}$. So if $i\neq j$ then we have $\frac{-2x_j}{|x|^4}$. In the other case we have $\frac{|x|^2-2x_j}{|x|^4}$, correctly?

Comment: Offhand this looks good to me.

Comment: BUt how can I compute the determinant?

Comment: Using the Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury formula. Your matrix has the form $aI_n+uv^T$, the determinant is $a^n+a^{n-1}v^Tu$.